# FieldMergeMap - Combine two columns to one

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

We have a Bug description column and reproduction steps in TFS, but our Dev Ops template has only the Reproduction Steps column. I would like to merge both Description + Reproduction steps from TFS and migrate to Reproductions Steps in Azure.

Azure DevOps Migration Tools documentation has FieldMergeMap listed but I do not see any sample documentation. Can someone provide a sample on how to configure FieldMergeMap json?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what I was looking for.

```
        {
            "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.FieldMap.FieldMergeMapConfig",
            "WorkItemTypeName": "Bug",
            "sourceField1": "field1",
            "sourceField2": "field2",
            "targetField": "field to be merged into",
            "formatExpression": "<h3>Field1: </h3>{0}<br/><h3>Field2: </h3>{1}"
        }
```